# requests-html module does not respond

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am a new Python user and I'm trying to web scrape with the requests-html module. I'm working on a mac with Jupyter. When I type

```
pip install requests-html
```

and it looks like I could install the Module because I get the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests-html in /Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.10.0)
```

Then I type

```
from requests-html import HTMLSession
```

and get the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-6-af86b1357aeb>", line 1
    from requests-html import HTMLSession
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would  appreciate any help for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `from requests_html import HTMLSession` not `from requests-html import HTMLSession`.

Read more [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/).